# What is a Hybrid Agile Approach? How Are Senior Business Roles Affected?

Tags: scrum, dsdm

Hi guys I was wondering if I got it right that a hybrid approach is a mix two different agile approaches if so what happens to senior project business level roles in hybrid approach eg: scrum and dsdm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a strange combination - Scrum and DSDM -, but those roles can stay in Scrum. The Product Owner shall be a SPOC (Single Point of Contact) between business representatives and the Scrum Team.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Hybrid agile Approach is a combination of agile and traditional project management methodologies. These are practiced by teams that want to move to agile but have been using the traditional methods for a long time.